# how to correctly call a callback function for an JSON object

Tags: javascript, extjs

**Details:**

I am getting data for the `html5` Geolocation; specifically longitude and latitude. I am trying to create a plugin that anyone can call from within a project and get the long and lat.

I have read this [How to return response from an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593) but I wondering how I should call these functions.

I placed a `extjs` tag even though I think it's more of a `javascript` core question

**JavaScript:**

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.GeoLocation', {
    alias: 'plugin.ux.geolocation',

    constructor: function() {
        console.log('called 1');
        this.duh = 'yes';
        this.init();

    },

    init: function () {
        console.log('called 2');
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.test, this.test);        
    },

    test: function(init) {
        console.log('called 3');
        this.duh = "amazing";
    }

});

var geo = new Ext.ux.GeoLocation();
geo.test(); // this gets called twice though... incorrect?
```

[Here is a FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/738uq/)

The console out output is:

```
called 1 
called 2 
called 3 
called 3
```

Is this a bad practice? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

On your class constructor you're passing the `test` function to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. Do you know what that other function do? most likely is calling test internally.

You can check by doing:

```
var geo = new Ext.ux.GeoLocation();
console.log("middle");
geo.test();
```

Then you should see "middle" printed between the two "called 3" lines.

Comment: So, am I fine with just calling `geo.test()`? At this point by the time I get to `geo.test()` the `getCurrentPosition()` has already fired... correct?

Comment: I don't know extjs but it seems that "init" is some kind of "constructor" that gets invoked on object construction. So yes, getCurrentPosition() is getting executed on object construction (that's why you also see the "called 2" printed before "called 3")

Comment: I'm calling `this.init()` in the constructor. The constructor gets called internally. I actually removed `init()` and it still works...

Comment: nope, I was asking the wrong question. what i was looking for was impossible for `javascript`, your answer let me to it though, so thank you :)